# Matrix multiplication in SYCL using nd_range

Tags: c++, sycl

I am doing matrix multiplication in sycl, but having some problems. I am using 2 (4x4) Matrices for multiplication and on **first iteration of for loop it works** but on **second iteration when  i = 1 it works fine until  C[11] = A[11]*B[15]** but then it skips 1 multiplication and move forward. I know the problem why it skips but unfortunately i have been unable to change matrix B index properly. Kindly if someone can help i will greatly appreciate it. Thanks

Here is the code
**Matsize= 4,
Blocksize = 4** also i know for loop will be equal to matsize it is 2 just to get clear idea of execution flow

```
{
    range<1> dimensions(matSize * matSize);
    const property_list props = { property::buffer::use_host_ptr() };
    buffer<T> A_buf(MA, dimensions, props);
    buffer<T> B_buf(MB, dimensions, props);
    buffer<T> C_buf(MC, dimensions, props);

    myQueue.submit([&](handler& cgh) {
        auto A_ptr = A_buf.template get_access<access::mode::read>(cgh);
        auto B_ptr = B_buf.template get_access<access::mode::read_write>(cgh);
        auto C_ptr = C_buf.template get_access<access::mode::write>(cgh);
        auto localRange = range<1>(blockSize* blockSize);

        accessor<T, 1, access::mode::read_write, access::target::local>
            C(matSize * matSize, cgh);

        cgh.parallel_for<mxm_kernel>(
            nd_range<2>(range<2>{matSize, matSize},   
                range<2>{blockSize, blockSize}),  
            [=](nd_item<2> item) {

            const auto id_x = item.get_global_id(0);
            const auto id_y = item.get_global_id(1);

            const auto width = item.get_group_range(0) * item.get_local_range(0);

            const auto index = id_x * width + id_y;
            const auto index2 = id_y * width + id_x;

            for (int i = 0; i < 2 ; i++) {

                C[index] += A_ptr[index] * B_ptr[index2 + i ];
            }
            out << "C is!" << C[index] << sycl::endl;

            item.barrier(cl::sycl::access::fence_space::local_space);
            C_ptr[index] = C[index];
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: It's not totally clear what you are trying to do here. You seem to have taken the sample matrix multiplication code provided by ComputeCpp but it's not clear why you have made the changes you have. I'd suggest taking the working sample and looking at how the workflow operates on that.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Yes it does have some components of sample code but sample code works only for matrices with size of power of 2, but i am trying to do it for any matrix size.